Why can’t flying wings enter a flat spin?
In this answer, it states:

Naturally stable flying wings never enter a flat spin; their spin modes are all fairly steep due to the lack of a strong inertial moment from the lengthwise distribution of masses.

I don’t think I fully understand what this quote is trying to say.
What part of a flying wing prevents it from flat spinning? If a normal airplane can flat spin, why can’t a flying wing?
In other words, which of the characteristics that differentiate a normal airplane from a flying wing prevent said flying wing from flat spinning?

In order to maintain a flat spin, an airplane with natural longitudinal stability needs a strong pitch-up moment. Without it, the tail will weathervane it into a dive. What provides this pitch-up moment is the lengthwise arrangement of masses which produces a high moment of inertia around the pitch axis.
When spinning, the nose of the fuselage is closer to the axis of rotation, so its masses experience a lower centrifugal acceleration than the masses near the tail, where the rotation radius is much larger. This will pull the parts farther from the axis of rotation more away from this axis than the parts closer to it. The consequence is a pitching moment which pulls the fuselage into a horizontal orientation - just what a flat spin requires.
A flying wing has a small moment of inertia around the pitch axis and, consequently, will experience a much smaller inertial pitch-up moment than an airplane with a fuselage and separate tail surfaces.

You could say the flying wing makes a poor gyroscope.
